# How to handle JSP dropdown list error handling

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, drop-down-menu

I am populating my database data to be the option in my dropdown list

```
<select name="AccountType">
                    <option value = "1">Please Select</option>
                        <c:forEach items="${UserItem}" var="AccountType">
                            <option value="${AccountType.getRoleId()}">${AccountType.getRoleName()}</option>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </select>

<%
                                if (errors.containsKey("AccountType"))
                                {
                                    out.println("<span class=\"warning\">" + errors.get("AccountType") + "</span>");
                                }
                            %>
```

In my servlet here's the code

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        logger.debug("Add User page requested");
        List<User> UserItems = new UserDAO().RoleTypeList();
        req.setAttribute("UserItem", UserItems);
        jsp.forward(req, resp);
    }
```

Now to determine if the user forgot to select the 1st option (please select) in the dropdown list I tried this code

```
long AccountType = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("AccountType"));
        if ("1".equals(AccountType))
        {
            errors.put("AccountType", "Required");
        }
        else if (req.getParameter("AccountType") != null && !"".equals(req.getParameter("AccountType")))
        {
            long RoleId = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("AccountType"));
            emsItem.setRoleId(RoleId);
        }
```

When I clicked the submit button nothing happened. Also my dropdown list' items were gone so I just need to go back the page. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Where are you submitting your jsp? To the same jsp? To a servlet? To the same servlet you used before? What are you doing after you do 'errors.put()'? Are you forwarding the request? Where?

Comment: I replaced my validation with 
`String accountType = req.getParameter("AccountType");
if ("1".equals(accountType))` and its fine now. The only problem is when I submit and there's one or more textbox and even the droplist, the dropdown list items were gone. Why?

Comment: are you executing req.setAttribute("UserItem", UserItems); again?

Comment: @EstebanAliverti it was located in my doGet() method

Comment: I have no idea why you tagged `[javascript]`, so it seemed like that you're confusing/mixing JSP *scriptlets* with JavaScript. I recommend to take a pause and get the basic concepts straight by reading a sane HTML/CSS/JS and Java/JSP/Servlet book/tutorial/resource.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in these two lines:

```
long AccountType = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("AccountType"));
if ("1".equals(AccountType))
```

`Integer.parseInt()` returns an int. Why are you storing it into a long?
Then once you have this long, you test if the long is equal to the String `"1"`. A long will never be equal to a String, since they're not even of the same type.

Either use

```
int accountType = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("AccountType"));
if (accountType == 1)
```

or

```
String accountType = req.getParameter("AccountType");
if ("1".equals(accountType))
```

And please respect the Java naming conventions: variables start with a lower-case letter.

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It it can already determine if the "Please select" option was selected. But after I submit with either one or more text or even dropdown list have no content, The dropdown list data was missing after I clicked the submit button

Comment: That's another, different problem. You of course need to repopulate the dropdown each time the page is redisplayed.

Comment: But my option for calling data are held in my doGet method...Why is that when I submit the page my dropdown list items were gone?

Comment: I place the `List<User> UserItems = new UserDAO().RoleTypeList();
  req.setAttribute("UserItem", UserItems);` in my doPost() and it repopulated. The problem now is for example I tried to leave one textbox with no item. When I submit all the textbox that I have placed a text before submitting were gone. How to prevent this?

Comment: You need to repopulate them with what the user submitted. `<input type="text" name="foo" value="<c:out value='${param.foo}'/>"/>`. You're staring to reimplement what MVC frameworks like Stripes or Spring MVC help to do, or do for you: form validation and repopulation.